# I need to query table for values in two duplicate columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working in ASP.NET Core. I have a problem with querying rows which have same `User_id` and `Definition_id`, if there are any like that, I need ID of the row.

```
+----+---------+---------------+
| Id | User-id | Definition-id |
+----+---------+---------------+
|  1 |       1 |             1 |
|  2 |       2 |             1 |
|  3 |       2 |             2 |
|  4 |       3 |             1 |
|  5 |       4 |             1 |
|  6 |       4 |             1 |
|  7 |       5 |             2 |
|  8 |       6 |             1 |
+----+---------+---------------+
```

I need to query table like this, to return { 5, 6 } to me, because of them having same user AND definition ids.

I've tried `Groupby` for both values, but I can't get the `IQueryable` or `IGrouping` to give me the id of specific row.

I'd imagine it to work like that, but it ain't.

```
var placementsWithDuplicates =
    from p in _context.Placements
    group p by new { p.User_id, p.Definition_id } into what
    select new
    {
        Id = what.Id,
        User = what.User_id,
        Defi = what.Definition_id,
    };

foreach (var p in placementsWithDuplicates)
{
    issues.Add(new IssueModel()
        {
            Type = "Praxe ID[" + p.Id + "]",
            Name = "User id [" + p.User + "], Definition id [" + p.Defi + "]",
            Detail = "So user shouldnt have data for more definitons!"
        });
};
```

Thanks to Satish Hirpara for best answer, it needed a little update so I post the thing that ended up working well:

```
var B = from p in _context.Placements
        group p by new { p.User_id, p.Definition_id } into what
        where what.Count() > 1
        select new
        {
            User_id = what.Key.User_id,
            Definition_id = what.Key.Definition_id
        };

var placementsWithDuplicates = from A in _context.Placements
                               join b in B on new { A.User_id, A.Definition_id } equals new { b.User_id, b.Definition_id }
                               select A;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below SQL query:

```
    SELECT A.* 
    FROM Placements A 
    INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT User_id, Definition_id FROM Placements 
      GROUP BY User_Id, Definition_id 
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) B 
     ON A.User_id = B.User_id AND A.Defination_id = 
     B.Defination_id
```

You can create a temp table to avoid join of sub query.

If you want linq query then I tried to create it from above query, please find it below:

```
 --- sub query
 var B = from p in Placements 
 group p by new { p.User_id, p.Definition_id } into what 
 where what.count() > 1
 select new
   { User_id = what.User_id, 
     Definition_id =what.Definition_id 
    }; 

    --- join
    Var result =  from A in Placements
                          Join B ON A.User_id = B.User_id 
                          AND A.Defination_id = B.Defination_id
                          Select A
```

Please try this one.

Comment: First, thank you very much! I used that linq query, but it needed a bit tweaking tho, so i updated my question to contain the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var placementsWithDuplicates = from p in _context.Placements.Where(m => m.User_id == m.Definition_id)
select new {
    Id = p.Id,
    User = p.User_id,
    Defi = p.Definition_id,
};

// this is same as the top one
var placementsWithDuplicates = from p in _context.Placements where p.User_id == p.Definition_id
select new {
    Id = p.Id,
    User = p.User_id,
    Defi = p.Definition_id,
};

foreach (var p in placementsWithDuplicates)
{
    issues.Add(new IssueModel()
        {
            Type = "Praxe ID[" + p.Id + "]",
            Name = "User id [" + p.User + "], Definition id [" + p.Defi + "]",
            Detail = "So user shouldnt have data for more definitons!"
        });
};
```